# Implementing Merge Sort in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to implement simple **merge sort** algorithm in Python.

```
arr=[1,3,5,2,4,6]
n=6
l=0
h=n-1

def merge_Sort(l,h):
    if(l==h):
        return arr[l]

    m=(h+l)//2
    arr1=merge_Sort(l,m)
    arr2=merge_Sort(m+1,h)

    s1=m-l
    s2=h-(m+1)
    mer=[]
    k1=k2=0

    while(k1<=s1 or k2<=s2):
        if(arr1[k1] < arr2[k2]):
            mer.append(arr1[k1])
            k1+=1
        else:
            mer.append(arr2[k2])
            k2+=1

    if(k1>s1):
        while(k2<=s2):
            mer.append(arr2[k2])
            k2+=1

    if(k2>s2):
        while(k1<=s1):
            mer.append(arr1[k1])
            k1+=1    

    return mer

res=merge_Sort(l,h)

print(res)
```

But I'm getting this error message when running the above code:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Can anybody explain to me why I'm geting this error?

Comment: Where is `arr` defined?

Comment: On what line does it crush?

Comment: It doesn't look like that you posted the complete code. At line 3 there is 'arr' which I don't see is defined anywhere. By the way, which python version you are using? Also, can you provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri See now I've updated the code.

Comment: @DavidMašek It crushes on Line 16, 25 and 45.

Comment: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` You get this error when you try to access `int` object as an array. For example: `a = 5` and you do `a[2]`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Ok I get it Now

Comment: You should be aware that an implementation of a sort that doesn't have anyway to use it on a particular list isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    if(l==h):
        return arr[l]
```

into:

```
    if(l==h):
        return [arr[l]]
```

and this:

```
    while(k1<=s1 or k2<=s2):
```

into:

```
    while(k1<=s1 and k2<=s2):
```

I tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problems are here:

```
    if(l==h):
        return arr[l]
    ...
    while(k1<=s1 or k2<=s2):
```

Use this code instead:

```
    if(l==h):
        return arr[l:l+1]
    ...
    while(k1<=s1 and k2<=s2):
```

---

Side note, this piece of code:

```
    if(k1>s1):
        while(k2<=s2):
            mer.append(arr2[k2])
            k2+=1

    if(k2>s2):
        while(k1<=s1):
            mer.append(arr1[k1])
            k1+=1
```

can be simplified to this:

```
    mer.extend(arr1[k1:s1+1])
    mer.extend(arr2[k2:s2+1])
```

Comment: With this change I'm getting new error
"IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Why `s1+1` and `s2+1`, Why not `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: Because arr[x:y+1] takes all items from index x to y, inclusive. For example, arr[0:4] takes indexes 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` means you're trying to iterate (or use something like `a[0]`) over `int`.

Add this before the "crash line".

```
print(arr1, arr2)
```

Output: `1 3`

So you're doing `3[k2]`.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative method would be :

def merge_sort(a):

```
if len(a) <= 1:
    return a
mid = len(a) // 2
left = merge_sort(a[:mid])
right = merge_sort(a[mid:])
return merge(left, right)
```

def merge(left,right):

```
if not left:
    return right
if not right:
    return left
if left[0] < right[0]:
    return [left[0]] + merge(left[1:], right)
return [right[0]] + merge(left, right[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a relatively standard method:

```
def merge(left, right):
    res = []

    while len(left) > 0 and len(right) > 0:
        if left[0] <= right[0]:
            res.append(left[0])
            left.pop(0)
        else:
            res.append(right[0])
            right.pop(0)

    while len(left) > 0:
        res.append(left[0])
        left.pop(0)
    while len(right) > 0:
        res.append(right[0])
        right.pop(0)

    return res


def merge_sort(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst

    left = lst[:(len(lst)//2)]
    right = lst[(len(lst)//2):]

    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right)

    return merge(left,right)
```